# Vector Proof of Diagonals of a Rhombus

Tags: vectors

I'm stuck on trying to provide a proof in relation to: "prove that the diagonals of a rhombus bisect the angle of the rhombus using vector methods." I'm unsure what that means, so any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  let $\vec u, \vec v$ be the vectors originating from a vertex and drawn  along the two adjacent sides, with $\langle \vec u, \vec u\rangle=\Vert\vec u\Vert^2=\Vert\vec v\Vert^2=\langle \vec v, \vec v\rangle$ since the sides of a rhombus are all equal. Let $\alpha, \beta$ be the angles between the diagonal $\vec u + \vec v$ and $\vec u, \vec v\,$, respectively. Then:

$$
\cos \alpha = \frac{\langle \vec u, \vec u + \vec v\rangle}{\Vert\vec u\Vert\,\Vert\vec u+\vec v\Vert} = \frac{\Vert\vec u\Vert^2 + \langle\vec u, \vec v\rangle}{\Vert\vec u\Vert\,\Vert\vec u+\vec v\Vert} = \frac{\Vert\vec v\Vert^2 + \langle\vec u, \vec v\rangle}{\Vert\vec v\Vert\,\Vert\vec u+\vec v\Vert} = \frac{\langle \vec v, \vec u + \vec v\rangle}{\Vert\vec v\Vert\,\Vert\vec u+\vec v\Vert} = \cos \beta
$$

Comment: Greatly appreciated! So I use the same method when I'm proving for a different angle in the rhombus?

Comment: @W.Nguyen Right, this works no matter which vertex you choose initially.